# Material UI Version 5 RTL Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

In MUI V5 component `overrides`, `makeStyles` & components with `sx` prop not working properly in RTL.

The issue is in RTL mode marginRight not converted to marginLeft.

If I use `CacheProvider` then only styles with `sx` are converted not the styles with `useStyles`

Please refer to the following codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-forest-erxxy?file=/src/App.js